# Inheritance of arithmeticity properties in orbifold strata

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices, arithmetic-groups

Suppose $M = K\backslash G/\Gamma$ is a quotient of a symmetric space by a lattice. I don't know all of the proper adjectives to apply here (e.g. what should be said about $G$ and so on), but I wouldn't be upset if we just took $G=\operatorname{O}(1,n)$ and $K = \operatorname{O}(n)$ so that $M$ is a finite volume hyperbolic orbifold.

Edit: as pointed out by @MoisheKohan in the comments, I really shouldn't be asking about the real hyperbolic setting. Let's instead take $G=\operatorname{U}(1,n)$ and $K = \operatorname{U}(n)$ so that $M$ is a finite volume *complex* hyperbolic orbifold.

Now suppose that $M' \subset M$ is a connected component of an orbifold locus. I believe it follows that $M'$ is also a lattice quotient (of smaller dimension), and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about that. Now what can be said about the relationship between the arithmeticity of $M$ and $M'$? E.g. does the (non)arithmeticity of one imply the (non)arithmeticity of the other?

Comment: Are your symmetric spaces required to be connected? If yes, then the answer is clearly negative.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you elaborate a bit? (Non)arithmetic lattices have come up in the things I've been working on but almost as a side effect rather than the main focus. I'm not an expert.

Comment: OK, suppose you have a lattice $\Gamma_0< PSL(2,{\mathbb R})$ uniformizing a hyperelliptic hyperbolic surface $S$. Then $S$ admits a hyperelliptic involution $\tau$. Lifting $\tau$ to the hyperbolic plane, we obtain a lattice $\Gamma< PSL(2,{\mathbb R})$  which contains $\Gamma_0$ as an index 2 subgroup. The quotient $H^2/\Gamma$ is an orbifold $O$ with at least two singular points (projections to $O$ of the fixed-points of $\tau$). Hence, the orbifold locus of $O$ is disconnected, implying that it cannot be a lattice quotient (under the most common definition). Hence, your belief is wrong.

Comment: Ah I see. Let me modify my question to request that $M'$ be a connected component of an orbifold locus, that's what I really had in mind.

Comment: No, that will not suffice either. The orbifold locus could be a 3-valent graph.

Comment: I will write an answer of sorts, correcting your question in the process, in a little while.

Comment: Thank you. I'm also editing the question a bit to restrict to the complex hyperbolic setting (in which I think these issues may disappear?)

Comment: No, they will not go away.

Comment: If a stratum has dimension zero, is it arithmetic? Is this a matter of convention? If it is an intrinsic property the locus, they must be arithmetic. A generic hyperelliptic curve is not arithmetic. Its fundamental group can be enlarged to include the hyperelliptic element, which fixes an isolated point.

Comment: I think this paper might partially answer the intended question. https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is the correct setup:

Let $X$ be a symmetric space of noncompact type, $\Gamma$ is a lattice in the isometry group of $X$. Then $\Gamma$ has finitely many $\Gamma$-conjugacy classes of finite subgroups. Let $\Phi$ be one of these finite subgroups (I will pick one from each conjugacy class). Then $\Gamma$ fixes a symmetric subspace $Y\subset X$. The (set-wise) $\Gamma$-stabilizer  $\Gamma_Y$ of $Y$ is a sublattice in $\Gamma$: It acts on $Y$ as a lattice. The quotient-orbifold $Y/\Gamma_Y$ has a natural  projection $Q_Y$ to the orbifold $X/\Gamma$, the projection map $Y/\Gamma_Y\to X/\Gamma$  is an isometric immersion in the sense of orbifolds. This defines a (finite) stratification of the orbifold locus of $X/\Gamma$: The strata are $Q_Y$'s.

This picture serves a correction to the erroneous claim in the post "I believe it follows that..."

Now, one can ask meaningful questions relating arithmeticity of $\Gamma$ and the sublattices $\Gamma_Y$. If memory serves me well, arithmeticity of $\Gamma$ implies arithmeticity of each $\Gamma_Y$. However, the converse is false: It is surely false for $X={\mathbb H}^n$: One can build examples in all dimensions using the Gromov--Piatetsky-Shapiro  construction. I did not check Deligne-Mostov nonarithmetic examples, but, likely, you will find some arithmetic complex one-dimensional immersed totally geodesic suborbifolds. Since you like DM-examples, you should try finding such.

Comment: I appreciate the elaboration and correction, thank you!